# jupyter notebook list error after drive ran out of room

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, ubuntu-server, anaconda3

another user on my ubuntu server was trying to install anaconda in their home directory.  they downloaded anaconda to their home directory and installed it, and it took up all remaining room for users on the server.  So my user who is a different user, in a different home directory could no longer run jupyter notebook and I got a dead kernel error.  After moving their copy of anaconda from the their home directory to a different drive with more room, I am now able to again launch and run jupyter notebooks with my user, but I'm now getting the error below when I try to check for running notebook servers and get the token.  Does anyone know what the issue might be and can you suggest how to fix?  Again this was another user installing anaconda in their home directory.  I'm confused why that would effect my user with a completely different home directory, except that we ran out of room on the drive momentarily.

code:
jupyter notebook list

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 254, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2288, in start
    super().start()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 243, in start
    self.subapp.start()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 596, in start
    serverinfo_list = list(list_running_servers(self.runtime_dir))
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2388, in list_running_servers
    info = json.load(f)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by going to the directory

```
/home/user/.local/share/jupyter/runtime
```

and deleting files with names like

```
nbserver-xxxx.json
```

that were empty.  After that jupyter notebook list worked fine.